How to Implement Smooth Scroll using lenis scroll In Nextjs/React Poject
I've been trying to implement smooth scrolling in my Next.js application using the new App Router using the lenis scroll package, but I'm having challenges making it work
Here's what I'm trying to do:
Enable smooth scrolling on my home page I am using Next.js 14 with the new App Router.
I tried this code 'use client';
import Lenis from '@studio-freight/lenis';
import Hero from '@/components/Hero';
import SecondSection from '@/components/sections/second/SecondSection';
import ThirdSection from '@/components/sections/ThirdSection';
import FourthSection from '@/components/sections/FourthSection';
import FifthSection from '@/components/sections/FifthSection';
import SixthSection from '@/components/sections/SixthSection';
import SeventhSection from '@/components/sections/SeventhSection';
import SliderComponent from '@/components/slider/slider';
import EighthSection from '@/components/sections/EighthSection';
import Packages from '@/components/sections/Packages';
import HorizontalScroll from '@/components/HorizontalScroll';
import FinestExperience from '@/components/sections/FinestExperience';
import TenthSection from '@/components/sections/TenthSection';
import GreatAdventure from '@/components/sections/GreatAdventure';
import './globals.css';

function Home() {
  const lenisRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const lenis = new Lenis({
      duration: 1.2,
      easing: (t) => Math.min(1, 1.001 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t)),
    });

    lenisRef.current = lenis;

    function raf(time) {
      lenis.raf(time);
      requestAnimationFrame(raf);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(raf);

    return () => {
      lenis.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={lenisRef} className="smooth-scroll">
      <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col">
        <Hero />
        <SecondSection />
        <GreatAdventure />
        <ThirdSection />
        <FourthSection />
        <FifthSection />
        <SixthSection />
        <HorizontalScroll />
        <Packages />
        <SeventhSection />
        <EighthSection />
        <FinestExperience />
        <TenthSection />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;```


[![my code snippet](https://i.sstatic.net/yZYqFc0w.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/yZYqFc0w.png)


can you link to a sandbox it maybe an error in your other files

use lenis for react NPM
package name is @studio-freight/react-lenis
to use it you have to create a new component, name what ever you want.
"use client";
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { ReactLenis } from "@studio-freight/react-lenis";

const Lenis = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  return (
    <ReactLenis options={{ duration: 2 }} root>
      {children}
    </ReactLenis>
  );
};

export default Lenis;

and change your page to something like this
import Hero from '@/components/Hero';
import SecondSection from '@/components/sections/second/SecondSection';
import ThirdSection from '@/components/sections/ThirdSection';
import FourthSection from '@/components/sections/FourthSection';
import FifthSection from '@/components/sections/FifthSection';
import SixthSection from '@/components/sections/SixthSection';
import SeventhSection from '@/components/sections/SeventhSection';
import SliderComponent from '@/components/slider/slider';
import EighthSection from '@/components/sections/EighthSection';
import Packages from '@/components/sections/Packages';
import HorizontalScroll from '@/components/HorizontalScroll';
import FinestExperience from '@/components/sections/FinestExperience';
import TenthSection from '@/components/sections/TenthSection';
import GreatAdventure from '@/components/sections/GreatAdventure';
import './globals.css';

function Home() {
  return (
      <Lenis>
        <div className="smooth-scroll">
          <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col">
            <Hero/>
            <SecondSection/>
            <GreatAdventure/>
            <ThirdSection/>
            <FourthSection/>
            <FifthSection/>
            <SixthSection/>
            <HorizontalScroll/>
            <Packages/>
            <SeventhSection/>
            <EighthSection/>
            <FinestExperience/>
            <TenthSection/>
          </main>
        </div>
      </Lenis>
  );
}

export default Home;


Hey man. this hasnt worked for me. I created a component called it Lenis, then pasted your code. Then wrapped my page.tsx but still no change.

I believe you did not do something correctly or missed something. check this url.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r27g8g?file=app%2Flayout.tsx

This answer is correct. I had the same issue, but restarting the development server (yarn dev) made Lenis work (it didn't work before restarting it).

@NullEe doesnt this make every child component also "use client", sry im new to nextjs

This does not answer the question. Please use the comment function to comment questions or answers. Engage with the community to earn this privilege.

you have to add lenis in layout level and then you no need to make components as client component.  check this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r27g8g?file=app%2Flenis.tsx,app%2Fpage.tsx

and yes this is bad approach to doing this, you should use lenis component at layout level.
